# temperature reduction within a kettle over time

Tags: functions

When water cools in a kettle after it has boiled, its temperature $θ˚C$ at time $t$
minutes from the start of cooling may be modelled by the function.
$θ(t) = (100 – R)e^{–kt}+ R$,
where $R$ and $k$ are positive constants.

$(a)$ Explain mathematically why $θ \rightarrow R$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ ?

Here I used $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} θt = R$

$(b)$ What physical quantity does $R$ represent in the model?

I assumed this was room temperature

Given that $R = 17$ and $k = 0.09$

$(c) (i)$ Write down the particular function $θ(t)$

Here I plug in the values but keep getting answers around $17$ which I assume is wrong.

$(d)$$(i)$ Find $θ(40)$ and $θ(60)$ from the function.

Here I plug in $T$ as $40$ and $60$ to find the temperatures

$(ii)$ Would it have been more appropriate to have used the interval
$0 \lt t \lt 60$ if you were getting these above figures from your
graph?

Obviously I believe it would give a better representation

$(e)$ Find, by solving the appropriate equations, when the temperature of
the water is

$(i)$$ 65˚C$

$(ii)$$ 25˚C$

I have no clue here .

Comment: could you not just help with one of them ive been at this for days and got no where

Comment: Can you add the relevant work you've done already? I would be happy to help if you do that.

Comment: sorry im new to this:

Comment: No worries. You can edit the additional information into your question with the edit tab underneath it!

Comment: i started by mathematically showing it using a function box and equating the f(theta) and f(t) to R and infinity.

Comment: And where have you become stuck?

Comment: @DonkeyKong im 17 and have only really touched on this subject , but as a precursor to university ive been asked to complete a series of questions.

Comment: Alright, so. You just need to add all relevant information to your question and explain concisely what your problem is in order to get a satisfactory solution. First of all, how are you getting an error plugging in your equation in (c)? You have two constants you don't know, you're not supposed to actually ___calculate___ anything, just give the function form. And what is your function, exactly? Is it $\theta(t) = (100 – R)\cdot e^{–kt}+ R$?

Comment: the problem with a) is im not sure if im actually doing it right , sorry the error occurs in d) as im using the function \theta(t) = (100 – R)\cdot e^{–kt}+ R and all the answers are around 17 when t = 1 to 60 and i believe this to be wrong

Answer (score 0):

A few comments to get you going in the right direction, though you might get better response if you post this to the physics community on Stack Exchange.

(a) I don't know what you mean by "$d\theta/dt  = d\theta /d\infty$".  That is more or less a nonsensical statement.  A derivative must be with respect to a variable.  $\infty$ is not a variable.  Besides, derivatives are "all about slopes" and what you are looking for has nothing to do with the slope of the function.  You wish to know how the function behaves as t gets "very large" (i.e. as $t \rightarrow \infty$).  When we want to know such things we should think about taking limits...

(b) Why take logs?  What does a logarithm "do"?

(e) You are trying to find a $t$ when $\theta$ takes on a particular value.  So you need to solve the equation for $t$.  So, how do you "get $t$ out of the exponent"?  The answer to this is connected to why you are having trouble with part (b).